# How do I add a timezone offset to this query?

Tags: query-posts, offsets

Problem is that $today is pulling GMT from the database; I need to offset GMT by -6 hours; Have been unable to find a query with an offset like that.

```
<?php
   $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   $today = date('Y-m-d');
   query_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'performance', 
   'posts_per_page' => 4, 
   'caller_get_posts' => 4, 
   'paged' => $paged,
   'meta_key' => 'order-date',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'ASC',
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
             'key' => 'order-date',
             'meta-value' => $value,
             'value' => $today,
             'compare' => '>=',
             'type' => 'CHAR'
         )
      )
    ));
  if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is WP set to that -6 offset you need? In that case try [`date_i18n()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) to generate your date instead of `date()`.

Comment: Yes, WP is set to local timezone. I resolved the problem by using the following: $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours'));  Will test your suggestion.

Comment: @Ray Gulick yes, custom offset would be my second suggestion, but if you simply need it in WP's time then `date_i18n()` is less to think about.